# How to fill Spring Cloud Sleuth Trace ID into logRef field of VndError in spring-hateoas?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a `@ControllerAdvice` which is returning `VndError` from spring-hateoas.  `VndError` specifies a `logRef` field which is where I should be putting the Trace ID from Spring Cloud Sleuth. Is there an official way to do this, or should I just retrieve it from the MDC directly in my `@ControllerAdvice` `@ExceptionHandler` method?

Example Controller Advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var tracer: Tracer

    @ExceptionHandler(LocalException::class)
    fun handleLocalException(e: LocalException): ResponseEntity<VndErrors.VndError> {
        val traceId = MDC.get("X-B3-TraceId") // <-- Is this the correct way of getting trace id from Sleuth?
        val traceId2 = tracer.currentSpan().context().traceIdString() // <-- Or something like this?
        val error = VndErrors.VndError(traceId, e.message)

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(error)
    }
}
```

GitHub Example:
https://github.com/hughwphamill/spring-traceid-logref

Comment: Any chance for a small sample to replicate the issue?

Comment: Hi @MarcinGrzejszczak I've added some sample code and project above, thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation of sleuth? We specifically describe how to retrieve the tracing context. You should use the second way via the tracer.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to put that in an answer I'll accept the answer.

I looked at http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.3.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html

Ctrl+F for currentSpan().context().traceIdString() shows no hits though and it wasn't immediately obvious how to extract the trace id.

even traceIdString() shows only two hits and it's in some sample code for the section on Spring Integration.

Comment: Ok then can you file an issue so that we update the docs?

Comment: Sure, will do, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation we've described how to access the tracing context. To get the trace id via the tracer interface.